# Packaged Server option not available in Eclipse with Bluemix and Liberty plugin

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, packing, ibm-cloud-tools

I'm trying to customize the Liberty setup, following the instructions from this post:
"Custom Liberty server.xml configurations in IBM Bluemix", see: 
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/01/modify-liberty-server-xml-configurations-ibm-bluemix/

In order to modify the Liberty server features, I'd like to replace the automatic generation of the configuration file by a customized server configuration, which according to the instructions is called "Liberty packaging server".

In the Eclipse Neon IDE, I've already installed two plugin's, the Bluemix Tool as well as the Liberty Development Plugin. At the server tab, I'm right clicking the active Blumix server, but no option for "packaging server" is displayed at the menu. The default "push" option is working fine.

At the Eclipse IDE, is there a software component missing to create and publish a customized server package (beta + features) for Liberty? How can I run a customized packing without command line tools, using Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main ways to publish a packaged server in Bluemix:

1. You have (or create) a Liberty server instance that represents the server. For details on how to create a Liberty server, see http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/t_creating_server.html. Once you have the Liberty server created in Eclipse, you can just add the Liberty server to the Bluemix server on the Servers view and it will package the server for you during the publish operation.
2. You already have an existing packaged server zip file in the workspace that you want to publish. Then, you can just right click on the zip file and do a Run As > Run on Server.

For details, you can refer to https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html#packagedserversupport

The first method is usually preferred since you can continue to update the applications and also the server configuration file and do incremental update on the application by the publish operation.

Comment: The packaging of the server apparently works well, as I see my code changes are flowing into the Bluemix application. The issue is regarding the replica of the server.xml file. Any change done locally at the Liberty server.xml does not propagate into the runtime (files section app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml displayed via console.ng web console). Is there a way to force a complete packaging, or overwrite the auto-generated server.xml?  Do I need to create an archive file for package server, or is it better to package it to the Bluemix server? Maybe a server name issue?

Comment: If you are seeing application file changes but not the server.xml file changes, chances are you are adding the application directly to the Bluemix server instead of adding the application to the Bluemix Server.  For example, if you have a web project called WebProjA, do not add WebProjA directly to the Bluemix Server.  You need to create a Liberty server by doing New > Other > Server > Server and select IBM > WebSphere Application Server Liberty to create the Liberty server instance.

Comment: After that, you can add WebProjA to the Liberty server instance and also update the server configuration file or other files that you need to the Liberty server.  Once you do that, you can add the configured Liberty server (not WebProjA itself) to the Bluemix Server.  WDT will then package the content of the entire Liberty server in the form of packaged server, i.e. app + config, and push everything as a single package to Bluemix as part of the publish operation of the Tools.

Comment: Thanks for guidance. Doing a removal of all components and adding it by the sequence described above solved the issue, uploading the required features by using the command: "Utilities: Package to Bluemix server" at the local WebSphere WLP server. By this action the server.xml configuration and key-store files transferred into the Bluemix runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, if you want to publish whole server to the Bluemix follow these steps:

- stop your local Liberty server
- in Eclipse in Servers view, grab the local Liberty server and drag it to the Bluemix one. It will publish whole server with its config.

Check this page for more details - [Deploying apps with IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html)

Comment: Using the "grab ad drag" function in Eclipse, as described above, the IDE opens a Java Web Starter Application window, but no publish or push action takes place. Is there a command sequence that calls the right deploy sequence, like:  Utilities - Package Server to IBM Bluemix?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of right clicking on the Bluemix server, you need to right click on your Liberty server definition.
[image]